# Generate CSV, download to local machine and save to the server at the same time

Tags: php, download

I've got this PHP script (see below) which allows me to generate CSV file using SQL query and download it to my local machine but how can I save it to remote server (http://myserverblabla.com/uploads) at the same time to keep a backup copy over there? Would it be possible to modify my existing script to achieve that?

```
include 'class/database.class.php';

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"filename.csv\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

$database = new Database();

try{
    // Select query
    $database->query("SOME SQL QUERY");
    $data = $database->resultset();

    $fp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        if (! isset($ch)) {
            foreach ($row as $header => $value) {
                if (isset($ch))
                    $ch .= ",";
                    else
                        $ch = "";

                        $ch .= '"' . addslashes($header) . '"';
            }
        }
        fputcsv($fp, $row, ",", '"');
    }

    rewind($fp);
    $csv = fread($fp, 1048576);
    fclose($fp);
    echo $ch . PHP_EOL .  rtrim($csv, PHP_EOL);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo json_encode((object)['error'=>true,'message'=>$e->getMessage()]);
}
```

Comment: what's the specifications of http://myserverblabla.com/uploads ? can you ssh in there? can you use php in there? To download the cvs do you need to be login or similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've figured out myself...

I've changed `fopen`function in order to save CSV file into server:

`$fp = fopen('uploads/test.csv', 'w+');`

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply copying the file you generate? Just insert something like `copy(your file $fp, destination dir/filename);` after your `fclose($fp);`

Answer (score 3):

A simple way make a file upload to your server.
To do it automatically is a bit harder, but there's nothing like trying.
For that you need to know a little of AJAX, Json, JQuery and file upload.

A normal file upload you need in your client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

In your server:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

In your case you don't want to create a interface that get the file to the server. For that you need to use some ajax and json or Jquery File Upload.

Look on the site for exemples.

I have tried to do something like that but I got stuck in ajax posting, It worked but only within a form. The way around it's to send only the file to the server.

when you create the first code and the first problems appear I whill try to help . Two heads work better than one.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed your code check it:

```
include 'class/database.class.php';

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"filename.csv\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

$database = new Database();

try{
    // Select query
    $database->query("SOME SQL QUERY");
    $data = $database->resultset();

    ob_start();
    $fp = fopen('path/to/folder/filename.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($data as $row) {

        if ( ! fputcsv($fp, $row))
        {
            show_error("Can't write line $n: $line");
        }
    }
    fclose($fp) or show_error("Can't close path/to/folder/filename.csv");
    $str = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    print "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM
    print $str;
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo json_encode((object)['error'=>true,'message'=>$e->getMessage()]);
}
```

Also csv folder should have permission for write and read.